# How to setup boundary conditions for this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I am trying to solve a linear pde of the form $\Delta u = f(u)$ using separation of variables in polar coordinates in the half-space $\mathbb{R}^2_{+}=\{(x,y):x\in \mathbb{R},y>0\}$, with the boundary condition $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x,0)=0.$

In polar coordinates I know that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(r,\theta)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\sin(\theta) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}$$
and that when $y=0$ then $r\sin(\theta)=0.$ My question is when $r\sin(\theta)=0$ which condition should I use $r=0$ (which does not make much sense) or $\theta =0,\pi?$ I am guessing that the boundary condition  $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x,0)=0$ will translate to the boundary condition   $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} u(r,0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} u(r,\pi)=0$ in polar coordinates, right?

Comment: The boundary is on $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$, where $r$ is anything. The origin is just one point so you don't need to be too concerned about it.

Comment: I messed up in the second comment, I'm checking now.

Comment: Sanity check: $u=xy=\frac{1}{2} r^2 \sin(2\theta),u_y=x=r\cos(\theta)$, going with your setup $u_y=r \sin(2\theta) \sin(\theta) + r \cos(2\theta) \cos(\theta)=2r \sin(\theta)^2 \cos(\theta) + r(\cos(\theta)^3 - \sin(\theta)^2 \cos(\theta))$. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: Wait let me check again and fix it!

Comment: So by the chain rule $u_y(r,\theta) = u_r r_y + u_\theta \theta_y$. Here $r_y = (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})_y = y/r = \sin(\theta)$ and $\theta_y = (\arctan(y/x))_y = 1/r.$ So I am guessing that $\cos(\theta)$ in the second term should be removed, right?

Comment: Sorry, now that you mention it, $\arctan(y/x)_y=\frac{1/x}{1+(y/x)^2}=\frac{1}{x+y^2/x}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{r^2}=\frac{r\cos(\theta)}{r^2}=\frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}$ so I think you had it right to begin with. Not sure why my sanity check didn't work out, did I make some sign error or something?

Comment: Yeah actually I think your setup is right. So the point is that you impose the BC on $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$, ending up with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = 0$ for every $r$ at these angles.

Comment: @Ian cool, thanks for your comment!